# OSX: Get application windows + bounds

Tags: cocoa, scripting, external, cocoa-design-patterns

Is there a way to get the list of windows from another application and their bounds. E.g. using F-Script or obj-c or any other way (except AppleScript) to access the window contents of another (any other) Cocoa-based application and possibly modify it?

I am talking about
1) accessing the data (as http://the.layersapp.com/ does) and 
2) modifying it

...externally

Answer (score 1):

See these Stack Overflow questions: [Getting the main window of other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981453/getting-the-main-window-of-an-app-via-an-nsrunningapplication-instance), [getting the unique ID of another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311956/getting-a-unique-id-for-a-window-of-another-application) in OS X.
Basically, the two APIs you can use is [Accessibility](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXIntro/OSXAXintro.html) and [CGWindow](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Introduction.html).

Comment: I think Son of Grab is quite close to what I am asking but if this is the only way then I'd appreciate some (simpler) sample code other than that from the Apple sample project.

Comment: I don't know any, maybe someone else here can help you. Remember, modifying the GUI state of other programs from yours is a rather advanced technique. So everyone assumes you know what you're doing. Good luck!